# What's the meaning of keep up-to-date in context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> The point is that debt payments — interest and repayments of the
>   original loan — are easier to keep up-to-date for borrowers with a
>   rising income.

[Source: BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-30300633)

My problem is with the phrase "keep up-to-date".
It doesn't make sense *keeping up-to-date an owe or debt* to me.
I think *keeping up-to-date something* means just updating it with news and technology and doesn't mean *you can afford a debt*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although 'up to date' has the dictionary meaning of 'including the latest information, or based on or using the newest information, methods, etc' it can also, particularly in British English, have the meaning of not being behind or late with some kind of regular or scheduled thing, such as rent or debt payments, or in a medical sense, with vaccinations or other treatments. These are all British examples:

> Hopefully everyone knows that rent is a priority. If you fall behind
>   on payments and don’t make an arrangement to get back up to date it
>   could ultimately mean eviction from your home.
>
> I got a letter saying one of my loans had gone into arrears and that I had to bring payments up to date, pay an arrears fee, or face legal action.
>
> If you're only travelling to countries in northern and central Europe,
>   North America or Australia, you're unlikely to need any vaccinations. But it's important to check that you're up-to-date with routine
>   vaccinations available on the NHS.